# Reactor's StepVerifier: assertion fails in nondeterministic way on various step

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, project-reactor

I want to use StepVerifier in integration testing save operations in Mongo repository.

I prepared a method for inserting multiple UserItems for further verification:

```
Flux<UserItems> saveMultiple(int numberOfItems) {
    return Flux.range(0, numberOfItems)
            .flatMap { userItemsRepository.save(new UserItem(it)) }
}
```

`userItemsRepository.save` returns Mono<UserItem>

I prepared a test method:

```
def "Should save all UserItems"() {
    given:
    def numberOfItems = 3

    when:
    def saveResult = saveMultiple(numberOfItems)

    then:
    StepVerifier.create(saveResult)
            .expectNextMatches {it.itemNo == 0 }
            .expectNextMatches {it.itemNo == 1 }
            .expectNextMatches {it.itemNo == 2 }
            .expectComplete()
            .verify()
}
```

And I expect that next items will emerge in the order {0,1,2}. Unfortunately, the test fails because of `java.lang.AssertionError` in non deterministic way, on various step. I cannot figure out how to do it properly. It's my first approach to test Reactor flow. Anyone has an idea, how to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flatMap operator doesn't preserve order of the source and lets values from different inners interleave.
So depending on userItemsRepository.save you can have something like:

```
1--2--3--4

flatMap

UserItem2--UserItem4--UserItem1--UserItem3
```

if interleaving doesn't bother you but want to keep the original order you can use [flatMapSequencial](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapSequential-java.util.function.Function-) or if you don't want any interleave [concatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-)